# using material box for card images

Tags: materialize

I am trying to use material box for card images. My target is to click on card image and view it fullscreen.

```
  <div class="card large hoverable">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img materialize="" class="materialboxed" width="650" src.bind="movie.poster">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">${movie.title + " - " + movie.imdbRating}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
      <p>${movie.genre.join(', ')}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">${movie.title}<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p>${movie.director}</p>
      <p>${movie.genre.join(', ')}</p>
      <p>${movie.actors.join(', ')}</p>
      <p>${movie.plot}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that it could not make the image container bigger. So the image will be zoomed but because the container is small it couldn't show all of the image.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't suppose you've solved this?

Comment: @PaintyMan, Unfortunately not! But I submitted an issue: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue an fixed in their last commit:

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2091